# problemas ao criar event listeners dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/njszasq7/

JQUERY/Javascript

```
verificaCamposRepetidos(".teste", array1);
verificaCamposRepetidos(".teste1", array2);
```

HTML:

```
<p id="parte1">
    <span>VALORES de 1 a 3</span><BR/>
    <input type="text" class="teste"><BR/>
    <input type="text" class="teste"><BR/>
    <input type="text" class="teste"><BR/>
</p>
<p id="parte2">
    <span>VALORES de 1 a 5</span><BR/>
    <input type="text" class="teste1"><BR/>
    <input type="text" class="teste1"><BR/>
    <input type="text" class="teste1"><BR/>
    <input type="text" class="teste1"><BR/>
    <input type="text" class="teste1"><BR/>
</p>
```

o problema está ocorrendo quando eu vou digitar no bloco (`#parte1`), ele está falando para digitar números de `1 à 5` e não de `1 à 3`, parece que  só faz a validação da última function que foi adicionada....
(`verificaCamposRepetidos(".teste1", array2);`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema está acontecendo devido a variavel `totalPerguntas` que está ficando com o valor da ultima chamada da função `verificaCamposRepetidos();` para resolver isso basta descer a atribuição da variável para o evento do `.on()` conforme abaixo:

```
$(element).on("change", function () {
        valorAtual = $(this).val();
        totalPerguntas = $(element).length;
        //Resto da lógica
});
```

Segue o [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/njszasq7/2/) atualizado.

Answer (score 0):

Ontem a tarde me veio a cabeça de parar de escrever tanto o mesmo código js.
E foi ai que descobri uma coisa maravilhosa de usar ( complica um pouco no inicio para entender, mas depois vai que vai)  ...

```
<div> Menu
<ul>
    <li data-method="abreTela"> Menu 1</li>
    <li data-method="abreTela2"> Menu 2</li>
    <li data-method="abreTela3"> Menu 3</li>
</ul>
```

Com esse HTML, em outros tempo eu teria algo semelhante a isso no meu js para atribuir os eventos.

```
var tela = document; //ou outra logica para definir a tela e context atual..
tela.querySelectorAll('ul li')[0].addEventLis ....
tela.querySelectorAll('ul li')[1].addEventLis ....
tela.querySelectorAll('ul li')[2].addEventLis ....

// ou algo semelhante a isso recuperando por id, ou class, ou afins ...
```

Porém, quando adicionado um eventListener no objeto pai `div`, ao clicar nos objetos filhos, o evento também é disparado ...

Sendo assim, só basta implementar a logica para definir a execução de acordo com o que foi clicado.
Segue um exemplo demonstrando ..

Adicionado o eventListener no objeto pai, e na função Menu.actions, ele realiza o tratamento.

http://jsfiddle.net/statelessbr/deLLybho/

Comment: $("div").on("click", "li", function(){ }); Faz a mesma coisa.
Eventos são propagados do elemento alvo para seus pais até chegar em document.
Desta forma:
$(document).on("click", "div ul li", function(){ }); Também funcionaria.
ou
document.addEventListener('click', function(){ });